# Need to pass two arguments to Python script from OBJ-C iOS App

Tags: python, objective-c, ios

Im new at writing code in general and I need some help converting a Python Script to OBJ-C for an iOS App.

I have a python script running an XMLRPC server on a Network Bridge.

I have an iOS App written in Xcode4 that needs to make a call to the python script running on the Network Bridge when a button is pressed.

I also have an XMLRPC Client script written in Python that can access the XMLRPC Server.

Basically I need to convert the Python XMLRPC Client script to OBJ-C so I can run it on the iOS app.

**Python XMLRPC Client Script:**

```
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy, Binary
import time
yourAddr = Binary('\x00\x00\x04') # SNAP Address of this client application
ourAddr = Binary('\x4c\x6f\x8c') # SNAP Address of this client application 
CONN_TYPE_USB = 2
count =0
def listenForResponse(srv):
    global count
    """ Wait and listen for a mcast count message """
    eventResp = srv.waitOnEvent(ourAddr,1)
    if eventResp != None and eventResp['methodName'] == "setButtonCount": 
        # The count should be the first parameter
        print "The button count = ", (eventResp['parameters'][0]), "\n"
    else:
        if eventResp == None:
            print "time out "
        else:
            print "...not the response we were looking for; continue waiting "
            print eventResp['methodName']

#    print "mcastRpc setButtonCount to snap server"
#    count = (count + 1) %100
#    srv.mcastRpc( ourAddr, 1,5, 'setButtonCount',[count])
#    time.sleep(1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ The main program loop for this example """
    # Connect to SNAPconnect server via TCP port 8080    
#
#    srv = ServerProxy("http://192.168.0.x:8080", allow_none=False)
    srv = ServerProxy("http://192.168.0.x:8080", allow_none=False) #call from the xmlrpc library

#    srv = ServerProxy("public:public:http://192.168.1.106:8080") 
    # Connect to SNAP bridge node (We'll assume it is on the first USB port)

    print "opening serial" #remote procedure call being executed on the E10, telling the E10 to listen to the SNAP bridge on Serial port #1

    srv.connectSerial(1,"/dev/ttyS1") # for the e10
    # Continually listen for the count
    while True:
        listenForResponse(srv)
```

**My Code from Xcode:**

```
-(IBAction)getResponse:(id) sender{


    NSString *ourAddr = @"1";
    NSString *dev = @"/dev/ttylS1";

    NSString *server = @"192.168.0.x:8080"; 
    XMLRPCRequest *waitOnEvent = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithHost:[NSURL URLWithString:server]];
    [waitOnEvent setMethod:@"connectSerial" withObject:[NSString stringWithString: ourAddr]]; 



    NSString *result=[self executeXMLRPCRequest:waitOnEvent];   
    [waitOnEvent release];

    if( ![result isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ) //err occured.
        lblResponse = result; //@"error";
    else
    lblResponse.text = @"error";
}

- (id)executeXMLRPCRequest:(XMLRPCRequest *)req {
    XMLRPCResponse *userInfoResponse = [XMLRPCConnection sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest:req];
    return [userInfoResponse object];
}
```

**What I get from the XMLRPC Server After Pushing the "getResponse" button in my App:**

```
15:48:15:611 INFO     SNAPconnect Now listening for XML-RPC connections on port 8080
15:48:23:981 INFO     http_server connectSerial(1, )
15:48:24:003 INFO     http_server 192.168.0.x:51752 - -  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 479

15:48:24:010 INFO     http_server <?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
<fault>
<value><struct>
<member>
<name>faultCode</name>
<value><int>1</int></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>faultString</name>
<value><string>&lt;type 'exceptions.TypeError'&gt;:connectSerial() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value>
</fault>
</methodResponse>
```

So I see from this that connectSerial is only getting 2 arguments [connectSerial(1, )] passed and it needs 3. [connectSerial(1, /dev/ttylS1)]

If I try to pass multiple arguments with something like:

[waitOnEvent setMethod:@"connectSerial" withObject:[NSString stringWithString: ourAddr: dev]];

I just get a BAD_EXC or SIGABRT

**What I get from Python Server when I run the Python Client script:**

```
15:54:00:505 INFO     http_server connectSerial(1, /dev/ttyS1, )
15:54:00:534 INFO     http_server 192.168.0.x:51772 - -  "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0" 200 225

15:54:00:541 INFO     http_server <?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
<params>
<param>
<value><boolean>1</boolean></value>
</param>
</params>
</methodResponse>

15:54:00:573 INFO     http_server waitOnEvent(4c6f8c, 1, )
```

Any help or insight to this would be greatly appreciated! Sorry it was so long winded. I provide any clarification as needed.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: To clarify further for future reference:

Well its seems like I've gotten closer, but not quite there yet...

**If I use:**

```
NSString *const ourAddr = @"1";
NSString *const dev = @"/dev/ttyS1";


-(IBAction)getResponse:(id) sender{


    NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ourAddr, dev, nil];


    NSString *server = @"http://192.168.0.x:8080"; 
    XMLRPCRequest *waitOnEvent = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithHost:[NSURL URLWithString:server]];
    [waitOnEvent setMethod:@"connectSerial"  withObjects: args];
```

**The server gives me this:**

```
20:17:20:954 INFO     http_server connectSerial(1, /dev/ttyS1, )
20:17:20:975 INFO     http_server 192.168.0.x:52253 - -  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 467

20:17:20:981 INFO     http_server <?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
<fault>
<value><struct>
<member>
<name>faultCode</name>
<value><int>1</int></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>faultString</name>
<value><string>&lt;type 'exceptions.ValueError'&gt;:Serial interface type must be an integer</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value>
</fault>
</methodResponse>
```

So now I just need to figure out how to declare the "1" as an integer and then pass both and integer and a string simultaneously. So far everything ive tried has given me a BAD_EXC...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke a script on the iOS device.  You can in OS X, but not in an (app store approved) iOS app.

Comment: so you cant invoke a script running on another server from your App? Really I just need this as a test. Eventually the Network Bridge should be connected to a web server and the App will simply display the data. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My bad.  I skimmed your code.  You cannot invoke it on the device.

Comment: You want to look for examples of invoking a POST method using NSURL/NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to create an array containing your arguments:

```
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ourAddr, dev, nil];
```

and then pass that to your XMLRPCRequest:

```
[waitOnEvent setMethod:@"connectSerial" withObject:args];
```

Comment: WOW... I swear I've tried that. Well loks like were closer to the answer.



so its almost passing the correct arguments... just with added [] and ' '

Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: This is what I get back from the Python Server:


17:19:27:579 INFO     http_server connectSerial(['1', '/dev/ttylS1'], )
17:19:27:600 INFO     http_server 192.168.0.x:52626 - -  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 479

17:19:27:607 INFO     http_server <?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
<fault>
<value><struct>
<member>
<name>faultCode</name>
<value><int>1</int></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>faultString</name>
<value><string>&lt;type 'exceptions.TypeError'&gt;:connectSerial() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value>
</fault>
</methodResponse>

Comment: @swbooking if this answer is exactly what you are looking for, mark it as the correct one clicking in the big "V" that appears at the left side of the answer :)